# Symfony - set default role in ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I want to set **default role** `ROLE USER` for every user but don't want to have a relation for every default user<->role.

Meaning that I would extend method in the Role entity by adding that default role.

Problem is that I do not have array of roles in my Member entity, and I saw many examples for implementing that logic. Instead, I do have ***ManyToMany*** relation between WorkspaceMember and Role entities.

**Role Entity:**

```
<many-to-many field="workspaceMember" target-entity="WorkspaceMember" inversed-by="teamMemberRoles" fetch="LAZY">
        <join-table name="team_member_role">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="role_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="team_member_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

And in the **Role Class**

```
private $workspaceMember;

 ..... more code

 $this->workspaceMember = new ArrayCollection();

 .....

/**
 * @return Collection<int, WorkspaceMember>
 */
public function getWorkspaceMember(): Collection
{
    return $this->workspaceMember;
}

public function addWorkspaceMember(WorkspaceMember $workspaceMember): self
{
    if (!$this->workspaceMember->contains($workspaceMember)) {
        $this->workspaceMember[] = $workspaceMember;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeWorkspaceMember(WorkspaceMember $workspaceMember): self
{
    $this->workspaceMember->removeElement($workspaceMember);

    return $this;
}
```

And **Workspace Member entity**

```
<many-to-one field="member" target-entity="Member" fetch="LAZY" inversed-by="workspaceMembers">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="member_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
<many-to-many field="teamMemberRoles" target-entity="Role" mapped-by="workspaceMember" fetch="LAZY"/>
```

And in the **Workspace Member Class**

```
 private $teamMemberRoles;

 .....more code

 $this->teamMemberRoles = new ArrayCollection();

 .....

 /**
 * @return Collection<int, Role>
 */
public function getTeamMemberRole(): Collection
{
    return $this->teamMemberRoles;
}

public function addTeamMemberRole(Role $teamMemberRole): self
{
    if (!$this->teamMemberRoles->contains($teamMemberRole)) {
        $this->teamMemberRoles[] = $teamMemberRole;
        $teamMemberRole->addWorkspaceMember($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeTeamMemberRole(Role $teamMemberRole): self
{
    if ($this->teamMemberRoles->removeElement($teamMemberRole)) {
        $teamMemberRole->removeWorkspaceMember($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: If you need ROLE_USER but dont want it to be saved in database, you could add it to the collection every time you call getTeamMemberRole(), unless you need to do more than only read that ROLE_USER. What I don't know is if that will give you troubles when persisting.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done, similar to @alexcm's comment, is modify the example `getRoles` in the [docs](https://%20https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles) to return a copy of the `$roles` elements and insert `'ROLE_USER'` into that

```php
public function getTeamMemberRole(): array
{
    $roles = this->teamMemberRoles->toArray();
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

This both satisfies the security layer's expectations and hides the `ArrayCollection` from the rest of your code (IME it's discouraged to expose Doctrine `Collection` objects, though I can't find an authoritative source to back that up. Closest [doc](https://github.com/dborsatto/best-practices#collections) I've found)